# What Headers to use when using HttpResponseCache.get

Tags: android, caching, httpresponsecache

I'm trying to use [httpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) to cache some of my requests. Problem is, I'd like to know if the request is cached before making the request.

I saw in the source for [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html#get(java.net.URI,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%3E)) that there is a get method that takes in (URI, requestMethod, Map< String, List< String > >) and returns a cachedResponse. I've tried a couple different sets of (URI, "GET", Headers), but I can't seem to figure out what the headers would be, and every time I request a cachedResponse using get, I get back null, even though there is a response cached.

Has anyone been successful in using the get method to determine if a request is cached before making the request / alternatively is there a different way to check if something is cached before making the request? I understand I can use hitCount to figure out if the response was taken from cache, and I can use the "Cache-Control","only-if-cached" to force a cached response. I would just like to be able to check if it is cached.

Here's some code I've used to try to accomplish this. In the onCreate of the Activity, I do initialize the cache this way:

```
try {
               File httpCacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "http");
               long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
               Class.forName("android.net.http.HttpResponseCache")
                       .getMethod("install", File.class, long.class)
                       .invoke(null, httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
        }
            catch (Exception httpResponseCacheNotAvailable) {
                Log.d(TAG,"HttpResponseCache not available.");
           }
```

And then try to use it this way:

```
   HttpResponseCache cache = HttpResponseCache.getInstalled();
            try {
                HashMap map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                CacheResponse response = cache.get(URI.create(base_url), "GET", map);
                //response is always null
                Log.d(TAG," Response is!:"+response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Sorry/thanks/ Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: My **cache.get** always returns null here.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
HttpResponseCache cache = HttpResponseCache.getInstalled();
cache.get(new URI(url.toString()), "GET", connection.getHeaderFields());
```

That is how it should be done, but I haven't tried it yet.